# Gazebo 1.9 fails to load URDF (which works in RVIZ and is validate by urdfdom)

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have this irritating issue that I can not spawn my URDF model in gazebo. The model has been verified with urdfdom, and I can successfully use it in RVIZ.

When I try to do so I get the following error:

```
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1010] multiple inconsistent <self_collide> exists due to fixed joint reduction overwriting previous value [false] with [true].
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[sensor:ray], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <link>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error [parser.cc:299] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [World.cc:1469] Unable to read sdf string [..entire urdf model here]
```

The actual urdf model is here:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/72275ff3ff38abdb9280498ca7533654

I do not know what I could/should do to fix this.

Hope someone can help.

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4431/gazebo-1.9-fails-to-load-urdf-(which-works-in-rviz-and-is-validate-by-urdfdom)/) by [Rasmus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/495/rasmus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The xml used inside your  elements are from pre-gazebo 1.0 days. They are no longer supported. You'll have to switch over to using SDF inside your  elements.

[SDF Specification](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.4.html)
[YouBot in SDF](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/68989fe22ddc430909763eace37d45a4a4936e25/youbot/model.sdf?at=default)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-09-24**:
What about the controller:gazebo_ros_power_monitor and the gazebo_ros_controller_manager? Those seem not to present in the sdf anymore. The last one is replaced by the gazebo_ros_control I think but the power monitor?

**Comment by [Rasmus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/495/rasmus/) on 2013-09-24**:
Ahh, ok so now the issue is located. Thank you. I have update and deleted ad now it actually works. Only issue is that my .dea files apparently not are valid anymore. When i use all the "*_convex.dea" files i can see the robot, but it is not as expected. I'll post a new question about this.